# HTML 5 Video Playback GET operation Cancelled

Tags: html, html5-video

I'm starting to design a website and I want to take advantage of HTML5's video playback functionality. I am using a stock video that I downloaded from Youtube and edited in Blender to add a fade in/out and black and white effect, and rendered as an MP4 video file. My html is simple enough:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Strange</title>
</head>
<body>
<video width="1920" height="240"  autoplay loop>
<source src="videos/0457-0670.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your Browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
video courtesy of David AE Levy
</body>
</html>
```

The issue is when I load my page(only tested in Chrome so far), the video doesn't load. I checked the profiler tool and it seems when the page loads, there is a GET operation that is cancelled.

Has anyone else had a similar issue that they were able to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the issue. I re-encoded the video into ogg, as well as mp4 using a different program, and it played in the browser. So fyi to anyone who may find this useful, please check your video encoding.